# ngClick event not fire after html binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I binded html data from angular js post to Html div, but not ng click is fired in the binding html content.

This is my binding html div.

```
<div ng-app="SupportManagement">
   <div ng-controller="SupportCtrl">
      <div ng-click="openModal(5)"></div> 
      <div id="detailBlock"></div> 
   </div>
</div>
```

This my bind function with Angularjs Post

```
angular.module("SupportManagement", [])
    .controller("SupportCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.openModal = function (ticketId) {
        $http.get('SupportDetail.aspx?ticketId='+ticketId).then(function (response) {
                $("#detailBlock").html(response.data);
            },
            function (error) {
               alert("fail");
               alert(error);
            }
        );
    }

    $scope.openTicketHistory=function(){
        var id= $('#tckId').attr('prob');
        $http.post('SupportDetail.aspx/ShowHistory',
            { ticketId: id }).then(function (success) {
                alert("success")
            }
        );
    }
});
```

The place is I call the `openTicketHistory` function inside `detailBlock` div. And not firing the `ngClick` event. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Check This Out

```
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Angular Material style sheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.8/angular-material.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="BlankApp" ng-cloak>


  <div>
   <div ng-controller="SupportCtrl">

      <div id="detailBlock">{{myWelcome}}</div> 
      <md-button ng-click="openModal(5)">Test</md-button>
   </div>
</div>



  <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular Material Library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.8/angular-material.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Your application bootstrap  -->
  <script type="text/javascript">    
    /**
     * You must include the dependency on 'ngMaterial' 
     */
    angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])
     .controller("SupportCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
       $scope.openModal = function (ticketId) {


                  $http.get('SupportDetail.aspx?ticketId='+ticketId)
               .then(function (response) {


                   $("#detailBlock").html(response.data);

               },
               function (error) {
                   alert("fail");
                   alert(error);
               }
               );
              }

              $scope.openTicketHistory=function(){


                 var id= $('#tckId').attr('prob');

                  $http.post('SupportDetail.aspx/ShowHistory',
                     { ticketId: id }).then(function (success) {

                       alert("success")

                     });
              } 
              });

  </script>

</body>
</html>

<!--
Copyright 2016-2018 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved. 
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file at https://material.angularjs.org/latest/license.
-->
```

Comment: kindly use my whole code and try . its work fine here without any problem

Answer (score 0):

First, here are some best practices

1. You should not access the DOM from your controller, don't try to think like Jquery where you have to access the DOM element in order to update it (See [conceptual overview chapter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts) from angularjs docs)
2. Avoid using $scope in your controller, use "[controller as syntax instead](https://www.codementor.io/cnorthfield/why-you-should-use-angularjs-s-controller-as-syntax-6i001lr5p)"
3. Avoid using $http inside your controller, use an angularjs service instead

As for the solution, you can just use Angularjs's Data binding feature to bind the model (inside the Controller) to the view

```
$scope.ticket = response.data
```

in the view:

```
<div id="detailBlock">{{ticket}}</div>
```

Here is the link to a working  jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bhjd4kto/25/

**EDIT :**
if your goal is to display html content inside #detailBlock, you can use angular-sanitize and ng-bind-html directive, here is an example : http://jsfiddle.net/bhjd4kto/45/

Comment: İ tried this before but my problem is different. I solved this with angularjs compiler directive. thank you.

Comment: Do you get json data from your response or is it some html ?
if you solved it, Can you post the solution please ?

Comment: in that case i think you can use ng-bind-html directive without creating a custom directive. ng-bind-html does the compilation for you (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)